# Adding Disabled Class Based On Matching Indices

Tags: knockout.js

Attempting to "disable" a `div` if its index does not match a clicked `a` tag:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: slides" class="slidebtns">
    <a class="slidebtn" data-bind="text: title, click: $parent.activeIndex.bind($data, $index())" href="#"></a>
</div>

<div data-bind="foreach: slides">
    <div class="screen" data-bind="attr: { id: title }, disable: $parent.activeIndex() !== $index">
        <div>test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
... .disabled {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.activeIndex = ko.observable(0);
    self.numSlides = ko.observable(3);

    ...

    self.slides = ko.computed(function() {
        var arr = [], n;
        if (self.numSlides()<6) n = self.numSlides();
        else n = 5;
        for (var i=0; i<n; i++) {
            arr.push(slideModel(i));
        }
        return arr;
    });
}

function slideModel(n) {
    var self = this;
    self.includeImage = ko.observable(true);
    self.imageSrc = ko.observable('slide_bg1.jpg');
    return { title: 'slide'+(n+1) };
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

which does not work. Every `div` receives a `disabled` class.

As a test I changed the last div to the following to ensure that activeIndex is actually updating properly on click (and it is):

```
<div class="screen" data-bind="attr: { id: title }, css: $root.activeIndex() !== $index ? 'disabled' : ''">
    <div data-bind="text: $root.activeIndex()"></div>
</div>
```

However, I am too new to KO to figure out how to additionally output the screen $index when the .slidebtn `a` is clicked so I can actually check if the indices are equal (regardless, they should be equal because there are only 3 of each element type inside a container).

Answer (score 0):

Just add a disable binding that will give your element that class without any magic trickery -

```
<div data-bind="disable: $parent.activeIndex() !== $index"></div>
```

You can add an element to let you know whether they actually are the same value also to help debug.

```
<div><span data-bind="text: $parent.activeIndex()"></span> equals<span data-bind="text: $index"></span>?</div>
```

**Edit**

The above answer is if you are using the disabled HTML attribute, not for the class 'disabled'.  You would apply CSS with this selector -

```
div:disabled {
    display: none;
}
```

If you have to use a class for this instead, then you would use the CSS binding handler like you had mentioned before -

```
<div data-bind="css: { disabled: $root.activeIndex() !== $index ? }"></div>
```

However, all of that said, if you are trying to just hide it if it doesn't match then just use the visible binding -

```
<div data-bind="visible: $parent.activeIndex() !== $index"></div>
```

Comment: much simpler, but it still doesn't work which makes me think the problem is elsewhere. will edit to include more of my code.

Comment: As a note $index doesn't sound like a valid property to be testing the value of, I would try creating a div and binding that property to text: binding to see what the value is, maybe doing the same for $parent.activeIndex() then you would be able to see when they have the same value.  Updated to include that in my answer

Comment: for my 3 divs created from the slides array i initially get: `0 equals 0?`, `0 equals 1?`, & `0 equals 2?`. this should mean that the first slide is visible and the other two are hidden, but they are all visible. additionally, when clicking on any of my 3 `a` elements the first value updates properly to 0, 1, or 2.

Comment: That is because you are looking for the disabled class instead of the disabled attribute.  The standard HTML attribute for disabled state is what you *should* be using instead of a class of disabled, but I will update the answer to show how to use both.

Comment: Added a bunch of extra answers, if all you are trying to do is hide it if it doesn't match then you can do it like the last answer I showed.

Comment: i didn't think the method of hiding was the problem and it doesn't seem to be, although i do appreciate all of the options because i didn't know of them until now. however, every screen div is still visible, even the one that outputs `0 equals 0?` from the test. perhaps i should mention that i have an iframe with a separate page that shares the same objects and bindings? the `a` elements are in the main page and the `div` elements are in the iframe.

Comment: Most likely one is a string and the other is a number or something, remember that !== tests value and type, if you put != it would probably work but then that isn't the right way to do it.  Check it with != and then find out why the two value types are different

Comment: that isn't it. i'll continue to dip deeper into my code to try and finally figure the damned thing out. thanks for all your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

Additional problem beyond what PW Kad mentioned: `slideModel()` isn't doing what you think it does because you started off writing it as if it were a "classical" constructor that should be invoked with `new`, but you don't call it that way. As a result, inside it `self` is actually going to be the global object (since in a function not called as a constructor or a method, `this` refers to the global object). Thus you're actually setting global variables called `includeImage` and `imageSrc` each time you call it.

Replace

```
return { title: 'slide'+(n+1) };
```

with

```
self.title = 'slide'+(n+1);
```

and either invoke it with `new` (in which case you should rename it to `SlideModel` since standard convention is that classical constructors start with a capital to remind you that you need to use `new`), or replace

```
var self = this;
```

with

```
var self = {};
```

and end it with

```
return self;
```

and continue to invoke it the way you currently do.